# How to calculate the middle of the screen for a pygame.Surface?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to calculate the middle of the screen for image pygame.Surface object. I've tried to do the simple `screen.blit(my_image, (0, 0))`
but that won't do it. Is there a way I can calculate where to blit an image, so it's in the middle? Each of my images have different sizes etc.

Edit:

I've figured it out! I've made a function:

```py
screenw = 500
screenh = 500

# true_coords(pygame.Surface(...), (250, 250))
def true_coords(obj, coords):
    objw = obj.get_width()
    objh = obj.get_height()

    true_coords = coords[0] - (objw / 2), coords[1] - (objh /2)
    return(true_coords)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40954002/7690862

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the center of surfaces in pygame with python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953796/getting-the-center-of-surfaces-in-pygame-with-python-3-4)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Rect` class to do all the calculation for you.

Given a `Surface` called `surf` and the display `Surface` called `screen`, you could do something like this:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(...)
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

surf = pygame.Surface(...)
# set the center of the new Rect to the center of the screen
surf_rect = surf.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

screen.blit(surf, surf_rect)
```

The [`Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect) class has a number of useful virtual attributes, like `center`, `topleft`, `bottomright` etc which you can use to easily position a `Surface`. Usually you use a `Surface` and a `Rect` together wrapped in a [`Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite).

Comment: Thanks for replying!